# Local package asset with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I originally had an app using a `private/settings.json` asset. When attempting to make a package out of this app, I put that asset in `packages/x:package/config/settings.json`, and in the package.js's `.onUse` added

```
api.addFiles('config/settings.json', 'server', { isAsset: true });
```

I was using it successfully in the package as

```
settings = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('config/settings.json'));
```

until I removed `private/settings.json`. I now get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
```

If I only keep `private/settings.json`, instead removing `packages/x:package/config/settings.json` (also changing from `config/` to `private/` in package.js, the package, etc) I get

```
error: File not found: private/settings.json
```

(How) can I have assets that are only local to the package? Alternatively, how can I include/use global assets in `private/` in the package?

Answer (score 4):

I think it makes sense that packages wouldn't be able to access assets in the app's `private` directory. Otherwise, a package could accidentally expose your app's private settings or assets.

It sounds like what you want is to share your settings.json file between the app and the package. There are several ways you could do this:

1. Put the settings into a second package and use it in your app and in your first package.
2. Have a method exported by your package called `setSettings` that allows the app to load its settings and then pass them into your package.
3. Use Meteor.settings, and launch your app with `meteor --settings private/settings.json` instead of getting the settings from an asset.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense to me too. This was all in package, but thanks for the super-useful tip! Upvoted. The problem in my case was actually just a malformed settings.json.